# An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type enum Description

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I am trying to have the Description of an enum pulled from the resx file, but I get the above error.

Here is my code:

```
public enum FinalStatus
{
    [Description(StringResources.MyStrings.Status_0)]
    Error = 0,
    [Description(StringResources.MyStrings.Status_1)]
    Ok = 1,
    [Description(StringResources.MyStrings.Status_5)]
    Warning = 2,
    [Description(StringResources.MyStrings.Status_4)]
    Unknown = 3
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is correct; these values need to be constants.  You'll need to change your `Status_n` definitions to something more like this:

```
namespace StringResources{
    public class MyStrings{
        public const string Status_0 = "0";
        public const string Status_1 = "1";
        public const string Status_4 = "4";
        public const string Status_5 = "5";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. But I cannot find namespace StringResources. I created a resx file in VS and I see the xml format of the same:

 <data name="Status_0" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>"Error: User action required. Expand row for details"</value>
  </data>

Comment: I think you may need to define these values differently.  I don't think editing the code in the resx file is a good idea.