# c# an attribute argument must be a constant expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, testing, nunit

Why does my String array below give me an Error, arent they all strings???
"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

```
[Test]
[TestCase(new string[]{"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10"},TestName="Checking10WOs")]
public void Test(String[] recordNumber)
{
     //something..
}
```

Comment: Well anything that gets created with `new`, can't be a constant, right?

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.  It says you can't use an array creation in an attribute; which is what you're doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578368/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-typeof-expression-or-array

Comment: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-typeof-expression-or-array-creation-expression-of-an-attribute-parameter-type even better gives a true explanation and example.. next time do a google search on the exact error message ..you might be surprised what results yield

Answer (score 16):

This does not answer to the title of question, however it solves your specific problem.

You might want to use `TestCaseSource`, it allows you to pass multiple test case scenarios into the same testing mechanism, and you can use it as complex structures as you like.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("TestCaseSourceData")]
    public void Test(String[] recordNumber, string testName)
    {
        //something..
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCaseSourceData()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new string[] {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"}, "Checking10WOs");
    }
```

It will figure out that the first parameter is `recordNumber` and the second is `testName`

see the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 3):

The strings are all constant but the array they are in is not.  Try this instead:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10", TestName="Checking10WOs")]
public void Test(String recordNumber)
{
     //something..
}
```

This works because `TestCaseAttribute` accepts its cases as a `params` list.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error but when I executed the test on Nunit, it gave me the error "the number of params do not match". I was able to solve it using                                    [TestCase(3, new String[]{"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10"}, TestName="Checking10WOs")]                                    public void SwitchingLevelsFromWOLevel(int a, String[] recordNumber)                                                      I just passed a useless parameter and it worked. not sure why

Comment: @GucciProgrammer See my edit, your test's parameter needs to be a single `string`.  Oddly enough it does work, but you'll run one test with an array of strings.  I thought you wanted to run that test 10 times with a single string parameter.